# Scala question about examples in "Programming Scala" book

Tags: scala

I've been reading this free online book and I'm hitting my head against a brick wall at the following section: -

http://programming-scala.labs.oreilly.com/ch01.html#ATasteOfConcurrency

At the end it tells you to run the following commands

```
scalac shapes.scala shapes-actor.scala
scala -cp . shapes-actor-script.scala
```

Except when I run the last command I just get this error

```
shapes-actor-script.scala:3: error: not found: value shapes
import shapes._
```

At first I just typed out the code, but then figuring I may have made a typo I downloaded the code examples and it does the same there.

I'm running the latest version of Scala on Java 1.6

Any replies would be appreciated.

Comment: Just tried example from the source and it worked. Which version of scala do you have?

Comment: The problem is that Scala can't find the package 'shapes'. What does your file structure look like?

Comment: I've basically got one directory `scalaexamples`

Comment: ...and the Scala compiler plopped a directory inside there called `shapes` with the classes compiled

Comment: Try pointing your classpath to scalaexamples/shapes in your execution command.

Comment: Tried that, still the same problem

Comment: Interestingly, if I run the Scala REPL like so `scala -i shapes-actor-script.scala` it runs the script fine before going into interactive mode

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do this instead:

```
scala -cp $PWD shapes-actor-script.scala
```

Or maybe `$PWD/`. On Unix, anyway. Alternatively, try this:

```
scala -nocompdaemon -cp . shapes-actor-script.scala
```

The reason for this is that `scala` calls a daemon to run scripts, so any relative class paths are resolved against the directory on which the daemon was started. Tested on Scala 2.8.x, though I hope this changes in the future.

Comment: I have the same problem and the first suggestion also works for me, however the second one doesn't - unrecognised option (scala 2.8.1.final). I also note that the example program doesn't actually print anything unless I put a println(...) at the start. In fact it looks like a race condition as the output is different each time.

Comment: @meowsqueak There was a space missing.